# Search file for word delete line

Tags: php

I searched here and found part of a script that is suppose search for a word and delete the line. There seems to be a slight error with what I'm trying to do. It's not doing anything

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
//  Separate choice.php has the following pull down 
//  Select item to delete from list
//  <option value="item1.php">Item 1</option>
//  <option value="item2.php">Item 2</option>
//  ...... many items.

$workitem = $_POST["itemtodelete"]; 

$file = file("option.list.php");
foreach( $file as $key=>$line ) {
    if( false !== strpos($line, '$workitem') ) {
      unset ($key);
    }
}
$file = implode("\n", $file); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the single quotes around the variable $workitem. Using single quotes will make the variables "ineffective", so the strpos is working with the string "$workitem" (without quotes), and not the value of $workitem.

To have it work, use either

```
"$workitem"
```

or

```
"{$workitem}"
```

or, since you're only using a variable

```
$workitem
```

The second option is the one you should use in most cases but, as I mentioned, the third one is the one you should use here.

Comment: I took the single quotes out and tried with the {} and the line is still in the file after running.

Comment: Also, you should use `unset($file[$key])`: $key and $line are strings created for the `foreach` loop, and have no real connection to $file. Last, `$file` is just an array, you can't expect it to edit the file itself. To do that, you should do something like `$fp = fopen ("option.list.php"); fwrite($fp,implode("",$file); fclose ($fp);`: this way, your file is updated with the new value of $file. Notice that I am not using `\n` when imploding the array: that's because every element of `$file` already ends with a `\n`, therefore you don't need to add a new one

Comment: I did have the unset as you mentioned. For some reason it didn't post. I'll start working on the other items you mentioned as if I can get it working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, variables in single quotes don't get interpolated, second unsetting the key doesn't really make sense, you would need to unset the array element:

```
foreach( $file as $key=>$line ) {
    if( false !== strpos($line, $workitem) ) {
        unset ($file[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing it's the quotes around $workitem, just remove them.

Comment: Sounds more like a comment, than a real answer at the moment